# How can I create a function with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: rust, variadic-functions

How can I create a function with a variable number of arguments in Rust?

Like this Java code:

```
void foo(String... args) {
    for (String arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In general, you can't - Rust does not support variadic functions, except when interoperating with C code that uses varargs.

In *this* case, since all of your arguments are the same type, you can accept a slice:

```
fn foo(args: &[&str]) {
    for arg in args {
        println!("{}", arg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(&["hello", "world", "I", "am", "arguments"]);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8eab75bf1cea2d00df4f42ac3458aa83&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Beyond that, you can explicitly accept optional arguments:

```
fn foo(name: &str, age: Option<u8>) {
    match age {
        Some(age) => println!("{} is {}.", name, age),
        None      => println!("Who knows how old {} is?", name),
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo("Sally", Some(27));
    foo("Bill", None);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dfd79c6ca28a3c9705bdb2dffe9781a5))

If you need to accept many arguments, optional or not, you can implement a builder:

```
struct Arguments<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: Option<u8>,
}

impl<'a> Arguments<'a> {
    fn new(name: &'a str) -> Arguments<'a> {
        Arguments {
            name: name,
            age: None
        }
    }

    fn age(self, age: u8) -> Self {
        Arguments {
            age: Some(age),
            ..self
        }
    }
}

fn foo(arg: Arguments) {
    match arg.age {
        Some(age) => println!("{} is {}.", arg.name, age),
        None      => println!("Who knows how old {} is?", arg.name),
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(Arguments::new("Sally").age(27));
    foo(Arguments::new("Bill"));
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f1894e84541f9ee6120c7a0e8cf9da37&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Answer (score 35):

In the general case where your types may differ, you can use a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! print_all {
    ($($args:expr),*) => {{
        $(
            println!("{}", $args);
        )*
    }}
}

fn main() {
    print_all!(1, 2, "Hello");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5edad3d4718d9f05caaef062ddb2bb8)

As another example, if you want to fold over the arguments, you can do something like this:

```rust
macro_rules! sum {
    ($($args:expr),*) => {{
        let result = 0;
        $(
            let result = result + $args;
        )*
        result
    }}
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(sum!(1, 2, 3), 6);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e28f83f773033f7d57692a18f14c15d)

See the [Rust book's simplified implementation of `vec![...]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/macros.html#defining-a-macro) for another example.

Answer (score 8):

```
fn variable_func<T>(_vargs: &[T]) {}

fn main() {
    variable_func(&[1]);
    variable_func(&[1, 2]);
    variable_func(&["A", "B", "C"]);
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster Compiles now. Yes, i agree on the allocation part. Is there a similar way without allocation ?

Comment: ah yes, the macro is really not needed here. I will modify the answer according to your comment.

Comment: what if i want the function take the ownership of the array?

Comment: @qiuxiafei unless you can hard-code the size of the array (thus making it not variadic), or you write a variant for every `[T; N]` you want to support, you'll have to give it a `Vec<T>`

Comment: @kbolino yes, i thinks Vec<T> is the only solution.