# How to write a macro that displays the file and line number and a variable number of arguments?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I've found several useful macros in Rust, namely: `file!(), line!(), stringify!()` I've also found that Rust allows macros with variable arguments, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951503/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-a-variable-number-of-arguments):

```
macro_rules! print_all {
    ($($args:expr),*) => {{
        $(
            println!("{}", $args);
        )*
    }}
}
```

My goal is to somehow combine all those macros inside one which I will use during troubleshooting/debugging. So calling `trace!` macro on the following example:

```
let a: i32 = 1;
let b: i32 = 2;
trace!(a,b)
```

should expand to something like this:

```
println!("TRACE: file: {}, line: {}, a: {}, b: {}", file!(), line!(), a, b);
```

Is it possible? If yes, how would such a macro work?

Comment: Not to rain on creativity, but this looks *very* similar to the standard [`dbg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html) macro (still a valid question to ask how it'd work)

Comment: Is there something you don't like about the answer provided, which was not accepted?

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this:

```
macro_rules! trace {
    ($($args: expr),*) => {
        print!("TRACE: file: {}, line: {}", file!(), line!());
        $(
            print!(", {}: {}", stringify!($args), $args);
        )*
        println!(""); // to get a new line at the end
    }
}
```

There is likely a small overhead to calling `print!` multiple times, since each call will result in a system call and will also check for IO errors. However, constructing a single formatting string for arbitrary arguments would need a procedural macro, which I think is beyond the scope of the question.

You could also use a `BufWriter` to limit it to a single system call, but it might not be worth the effort.