# Get all arguments from function

Tags: rust

I am currently working on a web server app:

```
mod rustex;
use rustex::Response;

fn main() {
    let bind_address = "127.0.0.1:8080";

    let mut app = rustex::App::new(bind_address);

    app.get("/hello", || -> Response {
        Response {
            data: String::from("hello"),
            status: 200,
        }
    });

    app.run_server();
}
```

My `.get()` method looks like this:

```
pub fn get(&mut self, path: &str, handler: fn() -> Response) {
    self.routes.insert(
        path.to_owned(),
        RouteOption {
            handler,
            method: String::from("GET"),
        },
    );
}
```

I was wondering if i could pass multiple functions inside`.get()` and get a list of it.
I javascript you would do something like:

```
function get(path, ...handlers) {
   //handlers is an array with your arguments
}
```

Is this possible or do i need to pass an Array as second argument?

What i want is to pass as many handlers as i want like:

```
    app.get("/hello", handler1, handler2, ....);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a function with a variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951503/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-a-variable-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable args are not allowed in rust (as per `rust 1.63`): Consider sharing an slice instead:

```rust
pub fn get(&mut self, path: &str, handlers: &[fn() -> Response]) {
    for handler in handlers.into_iter() {
        self.routes.insert(
            path.to_owned(),
            RouteOption {
                handler,
                method: String::from("GET"),
            },
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: well i see it does not work how i wanted it. However thanks!