# How to write a function that accepts an argument similar to format!() in rust

Tags: string, logging, rust, macros

Let us say I have a function like follows:

```rust
fn log(msg: &str) {
    //fancy_output
    println!("{}", msg)
}
```

Now, if I want to log a variable using the function, I must do it like so:

```rust
let x = 5;
log(&format!("{:?}", x)); // Assume some complex data type which implements Debug
```

Clearly this is a lot of boilerplate. I could remove the `&` by making the argument a string, but that does not remove my bigger problem: using `format!()` everywhere.

How can I write a function/macro such that I can do the following or similar:

```rust
let x = 5;
log("{:?}", x) // Assume some complex data type which implements Debug
```

I know a place to start would be looking at the `format!` source code, but it is quite hard to understand for a beginner like me and how I might implement it here.

Do I use some fancy macro or is there a simpler way?

Comment: `format!` is macro, not a function. If you want that behaviour, you'll need to write a macro.

Comment: @PeterHall my bad that is what I meant. I get that but how is the question. I will edit to make it clear that I understand the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format!` is a macro, not a function, which is why it is able to work with variable number of arguments. You can do the same with a declarative macro like this:

```
macro_rules! log {
    ($($args: tt)*) => {
        println!($($args)*);
    }
}
```

The `$($args: tt)*` means that the macro accepts zero or more (`*`) of any kind of token (`tt`). Then it just passes these on to the `println` macro.

Which you can call like this:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    log!("{:?}", x);
}
```

Comment: I guess I need to read the book on the macros again because I tried to implement it anf failed miserably.

Comment: But, if I wanted to, could I wrap it in a function like so: `fn log2<T>(x: T) {log!(x)}`. If so, what would `T` be?

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the source of the [log crate](https://crates.io/crates/log) for inspiration.

Comment: Also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951503/how-can-i-create-a-function-with-a-variable-number-of-arguments.(just documenting for future use) Thanks for the help.